# Positioning an object relative to another object at a certain distance

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to place four circles inside a rectangle, all with the same margin from the corner edges and although I can do this using guides or some calculations, I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

For example, can I select one of the circles and set it 20mm away from the bottom-corner edges of the rectangle, simply by choosing the edge line and entering the distance in an input field?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish, can you please include images and try to better explain it?

Comment: @WELZ Imagine a square with four screw holes on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do that. In this example, placing the circle 20 mm up/right from the bottom/left corner of the rectangle:

- Align both shapes bottom/left
- Select the circle
- Put the cursor at the end of the `X Value` field and type *+20* → <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Put the cursor at the end of the `Y Value` field and type *-20* → <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I don't know why I didn't try that myself! Great solution! Thank you also for putting an effort for creating a GIF as well!

Answer (score 2):

No, illustrator is a direct modeller. It has no understanding of relationships of objects.

However there is a easy way to do this. Offset the square by -20 mm then copy-drag the circle form center of the circle object by holding alt. and snap to the corcer points of of offset rectangle.

PS: there are cad apps thst can do this easily but they are not direct modelers.

Comment: Yes, I might do it in Fusion 360 if the design gets more complicated -- it's an enclosure box that is going to be laser cut-ed.

Comment: @Mahdi Only if you never need to make changes.

Comment: Why is that? In Fusion 360 I can pretty much design everything related to each other or some core variables, if that's what you were referring to.

Comment: @Mahdi you dont even need variables just constrain your sketch and it will update, you get thsi with 2 seconds of extra work. If, you uderstand how fusion is supposed to be used (and dont use newbie features)

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator already tells you the distance you've moved an object from its initial position.  I would either use guides, as you mentioned, or use the built-in system.

For instance, you can see that I dragged the ellipse below 30px from the top of the rectangle.  Just change your units in AI to mm instead of px:

[image]